# Jboss 7 Messaging

Tags: jboss, messaging

Our monolith application currently runs under Jboss5 and uses Jboss5's built in messaging. We are looking at upgrading our application server from 
Jboss 5 to Jboss 7.

Question:
While we upgrade from Jboss 5 to Jboss 7, would it be recommended to stay with Jboss 7 built in messaging?

OR
Would it be recommended to switch out of Jboss  Messaging and use a external dedicated MOM solution like IBM MQ or RabbitMQ?

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Red Hat support Engineer, I would think that you would want to stick with the built in ActiveMQ messaging if at all possible.  If your application is heavily message driven, you may want to have an external broker (or cluster of brokers).  ActiveMQ is a very good choice for an external broker.